# Play Framework and DB2

Tags: java, database, playframework, db2, playframework-2.0

I'm develloping a web application over Play Framework 2.0.

Since I need to access a DB2 database, I added the following lines to my application's application.conf file:

```
db.mydb.driver=com.ibm.db2.jcc.DB2Driver
db.mydb.url="jdbc:db2://host:port/databaseName"
db.mydb.user=user
db.mydb.password=pass
db.mydb.jndiName=databaseName
```

I connected sucessfully to this DB but got the following exceptions:

```
[info] play - datasource [jdbc:db2://host:port/databaseName] bound to JNDI as databaseName
[info] play - database [databaseName] connected at jdbc:db2://host:port/databaseName
[warn] application - play_evolutions table already existed
[error] application -

! @6a8ib4hd7 - Internal server error, for request [GET /] ->

play.api.UnexpectedException: Unexpected exception [SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2
 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.PLAY_EVOLUTIONS, DRI
VER=4.12.55]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon
fun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:134) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3$$anon
fun$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
        at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:133) ~[scala-library.jar:0.11.2]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply
(ApplicationProvider.scala:112) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
        at play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$get$1$$anonfun$apply$3.apply
(ApplicationProvider.scala:110) ~[play_2.9.1.jar:2.0]
        at scala.Either$RightProjection.flatMap(Either.scala:277) ~[scala-librar
y.jar:0.11.2]
Caused by: com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.SqlSyntaxErrorException: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-2
04, SQLSTATE=42704, SQLERRMC=DB2ADMIN.PLAY_EVOLUTIONS, DRIVER=4.12.55
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:676) ~[db2jcc4.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:60) ~[db2jcc4.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.hd.a(hd.java:127) ~[db2jcc4.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mn.c(mn.java:2621) ~[db2jcc4.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mn.d(mn.java:2609) ~[db2jcc4.jar:na]
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.am.mn.a(mn.java:2085) ~[db2jcc4.jar:na]
```

In order to solve this I tried to disable Evolutions setting the following line in application.conf file:

```
evolutions=disabled
evolutions.enable=false
```

But I am allways getting the above exceptions.

Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks

Comment: In the added config lines, is that a typo, or is the actual parameter really named that?

Comment: No, it's a typo, the values I've set up are different...

By the way I used:

evolutions.enabled=false

not evolutions.enable=false

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [DB2 -204 SQLCODE](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.db2z9.doc.codes%2Fsrc%2Ftpc%2Fn204.htm) means:

> The object identified by name is not defined in the DB2® subsystem. This SQLCODE can be generated for any type of DB2 object.
>
> ...
>
> Verify that the object name was correctly specified in the SQL statement, including any required qualifiers. If it is correct, ensure that the object exists in the system before resubmitting the statement.

It would seem the table `DB2ADMIN.PLAY_EVOLUTIONS` does not exist. If it should exist, try connecting to the database using a SQL client and execute `select * from DB2ADMIN.PLAY_EVOLUTIONS with ur for read only;` to verify the table does exist.

Also, you probably want to use `evolution=disabled` instead of `evolutions=disabled` (see the Play Git commit [`providing a way to disable EvolutionPlugin through configuratio…`](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/commit/6c8ee15faef4cf45cbde78ff6c2bd0d6c7f36576)) in your `application.conf` file.

Comment: That's the thing... I still don't have any SQL code and Evolutions is disabled (with the syntax you specified), so I don't understand why SQL commands are being executed...

Answer (score 7):

OK... Finally found out the origin of the problem...

Like I said I am using Play Framework 2.0 and was working in the forms tutorial project that comes with this version of Play...

As it turns out the command to disable Evolutions is neither:

evolutions=disabled
evolution=disabled

... But rather:

evolutionplugin=disabled

Thanks